# is it possible to control another app with an app?

Tags: android, iphone

I'm interested in opening a third party game like app that only responds to gestures. I want my app to simulate gestures on the game app. Is this possible in android? How about iPhone?

Comment: It is not possible until they allow you pass data to that app.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi thanks I thought it wasn't...